# Calculating absence duration for employee's working time

Tags: r

I ran into a problem in R trying to calculate employee's actual working time where I subtract the absence duration from the working time.

For one scheduled day there can be several durations of absence.

Example data frame of one scheduled day:

```
row_num StartDate           EndDate             Absence_StartDate   Absence_EndDate
1       2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 15:45:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00
2       2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
3       2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 15:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00
4       2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 15:00:00
```

You can reproduce the data frame from this line:

```
df <- data.frame(StartDate = rep("2019-11-13 14:30:00", 4),
                 EndDate = rep("2019-11-13 18:30:00", 4),
                 Absence_StartDate = c("2019-11-13 15:45:00", "2019-11-13 08:15:00", "2019-11-13 15:30:00", "2019-11-13 08:00:00"),
                 Absence_EndDate = c("2019-11-13 16:15:00", "2019-11-13 14:00:00", "2019-11-13 16:30:00", "2019-11-13 15:00:00"))
```

The main problem I face, is that some of those absence's are overlaping each other, for example row_num 1 and 3. 1st row has no use to me as 3rd row overlaps the first one (-120 minutes from working time). 2nd row doesn't affect the working time, as it's out of Employee's schedule, 4th row overlaps 2nd row and it affects the working time (-15 minutes).

for this example, the working time is 240 minutes and 150 minutes of absence, so the actual working time is 90 minutes.

How could one write a code to calculate the actual working time, given that the **StartDate** and **EndDate** can vary (but the same day) and there can be several absences (some may won't even affect the working time at all).

Tried using *intervals* from *lubridate* library and using for loop but couldn't achieve the results.

Thank you!

====== UPDATE =======

The code below by "@AnilGoyal" works fine for the most of the time. But, there's some kind of problem which I tried to solve but couldn't do it.

Here's example which doesn't work:

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(empid = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Date = structure(c(18213, 
18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213), class = "Date"), 
    presence_start = structure(c(1573648200, 1573648200, 1573648200, 
    1573648200, 1573624800, 1573624800, 1573624800, 1573624800
    ), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), presence_end = structure(c(1573655400, 
    1573655400, 1573655400, 1573655400, 1573646400, 1573646400, 
    1573646400, 1573646400), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), emprsn = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), absence_start = structure(list(
        sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(15L, 15L, 30L, 
        0L, 15L, 15L, 30L, 0L), hour = c(15L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 15L, 
        8L, 14L, 8L), mday = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
        13L, 13L), mon = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
        10L), year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
        119L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(316L, 
        316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L), isdst = c(0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EET", "EET", "EET", 
        "EET", "EET", "EET", "EET", "EET"), gmtoff = c(7200L, 
        7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L)), tzone = c("", 
    "EET", "EEST"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), absence_end = structure(list(
        sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(15L, 0L, 30L, 
        0L, 15L, 0L, 30L, 0L), hour = c(16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 
        14L, 16L, 14L), mday = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
        13L, 13L), mon = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
        10L), year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
        119L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(316L, 
        316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L), isdst = c(0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EET", "EET", "EET", 
        "EET", "EET", "EET", "EET", "EET"), gmtoff = c(7200L, 
        7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 7200L)), tzone = c("", 
    "EET", "EEST"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

> df2
  empid       Date      presence_start        presence_end emprsn       absence_start         absence_end
1     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00      1 2019-11-13 15:15:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00
2     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00      2 2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
3     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00      3 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00
4     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00      4 2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
5     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00      1 2019-11-13 15:15:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00
6     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00      2 2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
7     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00      3 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00
8     1 2019-11-13 2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00      4 2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
```

The code below, with some modification to account for several employee's and as later noticed, several Working Time's for one Employee in one day (for example:
from 2019-11-13 8:00 to 2019-11-13 14:00 and
from 2019-11-13 14:30 to 2019-11-13 16:30)

Because of this, each working time will have duplicated absences, but this shouldn't be the problem as far as I know.

with this example I tried to add **presence_start** to group_by, but **total_absence** comes as a 0 for both times, I've noticed, that both working times have only one instances of **d2=1**, maybe it's the problem? The **total_absence** for this example should be 6 hours and 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the scenario has been revised, I am proposing alternate `tidyverse` strategy.  Hope this works.

sample data modified a bit so that previous scenario also included.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(empid = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), presence_start = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), hour = c(18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), mday = c(13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), 
    mon = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L), year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
    119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(316L, 
    316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 
    316L, 316L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", 
    "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST"), 
    gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), presence_end = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), hour = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), mday = c(13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), mon = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
    year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
    119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(316L, 316L, 316L, 
    316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L
    ), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), zone = c("IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", 
    "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
)), absrsn = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9"), absence_start = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(15L, 15L, 30L, 0L, 
15L, 15L, 30L, 0L, 45L, 15L, 30L, 0L, 15L), hour = c(15L, 8L, 
14L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 18L), mday = c(13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), 
    mon = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L), year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
    119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(316L, 
    316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 
    316L, 316L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", 
    "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST"), 
    gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), absence_end = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(15L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 
30L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 
16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 19L), mday = c(13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), mon = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
    year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
    119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(316L, 316L, 316L, 
    316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L, 316L
    ), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), zone = c("IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", 
    "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST", "IST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
)), date = structure(c(18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 
18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(empid = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), presence_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), presence_end = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), absrsn = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), absence_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), absence_end = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 13 x 7
   empid presence_start      presence_end        absrsn absence_start       absence_end         date      
   <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>  <dttm>              <dttm>              <date>    
 1 1     2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00 1      2019-11-13 15:15:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00 2019-11-13
 2 1     2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00 2      2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00 2019-11-13
 3 1     2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00 3      2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00 2019-11-13
 4 1     2019-11-13 18:00:00 2019-11-13 20:00:00 4      2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00 2019-11-13
 5 1     2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00 1      2019-11-13 15:15:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00 2019-11-13
 6 1     2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00 2      2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00 2019-11-13
 7 1     2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00 3      2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00 2019-11-13
 8 1     2019-11-13 11:30:00 2019-11-13 17:30:00 4      2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00 2019-11-13
 9 2     2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 5      2019-11-13 15:45:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00 2019-11-13
10 2     2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 6      2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00 2019-11-13
11 2     2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 7      2019-11-13 15:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00 2019-11-13
12 2     2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 8      2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 15:00:00 2019-11-13
13 2     2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 9      2019-11-13 18:15:00 2019-11-13 19:00:00 2019-11-13
```

Now follow this approach (after loading both libraries needed

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#calculating both presence and absence times for each employee for each day

df %>% group_by(empid, date, presence_start) %>%
  mutate(absence_start = if_else(absence_start < presence_start, presence_start, absence_start),
         absence_end = if_else(absence_end > presence_end, presence_end, absence_end),
         absence_end = if_else(absence_end < absence_start, absence_start, absence_end)) %>%
  arrange(empid, date, presence_start, absence_start) %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(absence_start = if_else(rowid >1 & absence_start < lag(absence_end), lag(absence_end), absence_start),
         absence_end = if_else(absence_end < absence_start, absence_start, absence_end)) %>%
  mutate(presence_end = if_else(rowid >1 & presence_end == lag(presence_end), presence_start, presence_end)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(presence = difftime(presence_end, presence_start, units = "mins"),
         absence = difftime(absence_end, absence_start, units = "mins")) %>%
  group_by(empid, date) %>% summarise(sum(presence), sum(absence))
```

**Check the result**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   empid [2]
  empid date       `sum(presence)` `sum(absence)`
  <chr> <date>     <drtn>          <drtn>        
1 1     2019-11-13 480 mins        270 mins      
2 2     2019-11-13 240 mins        105 mins
```

**Manual** check- For employee 1 two **presence** times (row 1-4 & 5-8) (120+360=480 minutes) For emp 2 (rows 9-13) (240 minutes)

**absence** times for employee 1 (rows 1-4 - 0 mins because all are duplicate; rows 6 & 8 are overlapped - net absence (11:30 to 14:00 - 150 minutes);  rows 5 & 7 again overlap (net absence 1430 to 1630 - 120 minutes) - total for emp-1 is 270 minutes.  For emp -2 -- rows 8 & 10 overlap (net absence 1430 to 1500 - 30 minutes); rows 9 & 11 overlap again (net 1530 to 1630 - 60 minutes), row 13 exceeding presence (net 1815 to 1830 - 15 minutes) total -105 minutes.

*All tally with code result*

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 1):

To this problem, I propose a solution for calculation of total absence time, as follows-

Obviously the data frame will consist of employees therefore I have duplicated the df given, for two employees on a newly created `empno` field.

sample data used- (**Please note that column names have also been tweaked a bit**)

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(empno = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), rownum = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), presence_start = c("2019-11-13 14:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 14:30:00", "2019-11-13 14:30:00", "2019-11-13 14:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 14:30:00", "2019-11-13 14:30:00", "2019-11-13 14:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 14:30:00"), presence_end = c("2019-11-13 18:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 18:30:00", "2019-11-13 18:30:00", "2019-11-13 18:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 18:30:00", "2019-11-13 18:30:00", "2019-11-13 18:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 18:30:00"), absence_start = c("2019-11-13 15:45:00", 
"2019-11-13 08:15:00", "2019-11-13 15:30:00", "2019-11-13 08:00:00", 
"2019-11-13 15:45:00", "2019-11-13 08:15:00", "2019-11-13 15:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 08:00:00"), absence_end = c("2019-11-13 16:15:00", 
"2019-11-13 14:00:00", "2019-11-13 16:30:00", "2019-11-13 15:00:00", 
"2019-11-13 16:15:00", "2019-11-13 14:00:00", "2019-11-13 16:30:00", 
"2019-11-13 15:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")


> df
  empno rownum      presence_start        presence_end       absence_start         absence_end
1     1      1 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 15:45:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00
2     1      2 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
3     1      3 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 15:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00
4     1      4 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 15:00:00
5     2      1 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 15:45:00 2019-11-13 16:15:00
6     2      2 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 08:15:00 2019-11-13 14:00:00
7     2      3 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 15:30:00 2019-11-13 16:30:00
8     2      4 2019-11-13 14:30:00 2019-11-13 18:30:00 2019-11-13 08:00:00 2019-11-13 15:00:00
```

Calculation for absence time needs creation of a few dummy fields as explained below-

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(rownum, empno), names_to = c(".value", "event"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(presence = ymd_hms(presence),
         absence = ymd_hms(absence),
         event = factor(event, levels = c("start", "end"), ordered =T),
         absence_m = case_when(absence < presence & event == 'start' ~ presence,
                                absence > presence & event == 'end' ~ presence,
                                TRUE ~ absence),
         dummy = ifelse(event == 'start', 1, -1)) %>%
  group_by(empno, rownum) %>%
  mutate(absence_m = case_when(event == 'end' & lag(absence_m) > absence_m ~ lag(absence_m), 
                               TRUE ~ absence_m)) %>%
  group_by(empno) %>% arrange(empno, absence_m) %>%
  mutate(dummy = cumsum(dummy),
         d2 = case_when(event == 'end' & lag(absence_m) == absence_m ~ 0,
                        event == 'start' & lead(absence_m) == absence_m ~0,
                        event == "start" & dummy == 1 ~ 1,
                        event == "end" & dummy == 0 ~ 1,
                        TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  filter(d2 == 1) %>%
  mutate(absence_time = case_when(event == 'end' ~ (absence_m - lag(absence_m)),
                                  TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(absence_time = replace_na(absence_time, 0)) %>%
  summarise(total_absence = sum(absence_time))


> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  empno total_absence
  <dbl> <drtn>       
1     1 90 mins      
2     2 90 mins
```

I am leaving calculation of total presence to you, which should not be difficult.  Still if you have any doubts feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much, @AnilGoyal ! I should learn more about the lag() function, this is amazing, thank you once again.

Comment: Could you help me one more time? I've updated the question with another example which seems to not work. I've noticed that sometimes I get up to 2 working times for one employee in one day and this causes the problem.

Comment: Please Check alternate solution proposed